# Is it possible to set calendar in android by using adb?

Tags: android, adb, android-uiautomator

I would like to test calendar on my phone automatically by uiautomator.The manual way is to open calendar apk and click button to new a calendar, when reach the time you set, it will show a reminder on phone

The step to set a calendar is a little complex for uiautomator,it contains a lot of scroll or click. So is it possible to set a calendar in android by using ADB or sqlite command? Thanks

Comment: describe your question more briefly

Comment: @Lakhan I modifyed the question :)

Comment: Show some code you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its possible with the tools you have mentioned but you can [create an application to enter data in calendar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html).

You can design UI as per your requirement(may be a simple click of a button) to enter data. then you can easily use this app from UI animator as you wish.

Comment: thanks a lot, a good idea. I will try to use ADB send intent to Calendar to add